# Calling regular function vs. arrow function before their declaration in a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, arrow-functions

If I write a React class like this:

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component {
    state = {
        someState: this.someRegularFunction(),
        someOtherState: this.someArrowFunction()
    };

    someRegularFunction() {
        return "someText";
    }

    someArrowFunction = () => {
        return "someOtherText";
    };
}
```

Webstorm code assistance warns about the calling of arrow function `this.someArrowFunction()` saying:

> Field 'someArrowFunction' is declared after 'state' and is possibly
>   not assigned yet

If does not warn about the call of the regular function `this.someRegularFunction()`.

And Webstorm is correct, the execution fails when calling `this.someArrowFunction()` with:

> TypeError: _this.someArrowFunction is not a function

---

I've been looking for some documentation explaining this behavior, but have been unable to find any.

**Why can you call regular functions, but not arrow functions, before their declaration inside a class?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that code is functionally identical to this:

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.state = {
            someState: this.someRegularFunction(),
            someOtherState: this.someArrowFunction()
        };
        this.someArrowFunction = () => {
            return "someOtherText";
        };
    }

    someRegularFunction() {
        return "someText";
    }
}
```

Field definitions are processed in source code order, when the *instance* is created. It's as though they were inserted into the constructor before any other code (in a base class) or just after the call to `super` (in a subclass).

In contrast, `someRegularFunction` is a method of the prototype, which is created when the class definition is evaluated, not later when the instance is created.

This is covered by [the proposal for the class fields feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), in the specification text. (Reading spec text is not for the faint-hearted, though! :-) )

---

Side note: It's arguably a matter of style, but if you're doing that arrow function so that it can use `this` without your worrying about how it's called (for instance, as an event handler), you might consider making it a method and then using `bind` in the constructor (or effectively in the constructor) instead:

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component {
    someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this);
    state = {
        someState: this.someRegularFunction(),
        someOtherState: this.someFunction()
    };

    someRegularFunction() {
        return "someText";
    }

    someFunction() {
        return "someOtherText";
    }
}
```

That plays more nicely with testing code that may need to mock the function (by replacing it on the prototype).

But again, it's arguably a matter of style.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and gave me more insight into JavaScript fundamentals. Thank you very much!